# Wine-like MS-DOS runner for Linux?

Tags: linux, emulator, dos

For running Win32 applications, there's wine - a wrapper which translates Windows API calls into Linux ones.

Then there's DOSBox, which completely emulates a DOS-era PC incl. graphics. However the DOSBox team has [no intention](https://github.com/dosbox-staging/dosbox-staging/issues/688) to provide a light-weight, headless mode.

So my question is: is there something like that? I.e. a thin layer which would allow me to run MS-DOS (text) applications, use the pipe to redirect input/output but most importantly, be *really fast* ? (wine starts a couple of seconds for me...)

I've seen similar projects even for non-intel architectures (i.e. there's a bundled CPU emulator + a basic OS calls emulator which accepts a non-intel binary as its argument) so I can't believe there isn't something like that for x86 natively.